# I fear only one - Who am I?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, lateral-thinking

> The cave has me, the wind hasn't
>
> The stories, the pirates, the demons, the lands...all nothing if it isn't me
>
> The masterworks of science revolve 'bout me
>
> You'll all be blind if it ain't me
>
> The rock has me, the sun hasn't
>
> But still
>
> I fear only one
>
> The one that doesn't let me go.

Tell me - who am I?

**Edit:** It seemed as if *"all nothing if it isn't me"* was a standalone line, so I merged it in the second line

**Edit 2** *(These edit was made after four answers - apologies for this)*

Since the answers are *almost* the right answer, so I'll add a couple of more lines describing it.

> You won't be here if you haven't me
>
> I am the Poseidon, the Apollo and have half your food
>
> I am in the black not in the white
>
> I am in a chopper not in a plane
>
> The literature worships me, for it be horrible if it ain't me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer I am going for is the

> Sea/C/See

The cave has me, the wind hasn't

> Cave has the letter "C"

The stories, the pirates, the demons, the lands...all nothing if it isn't me

> All of the above is nothing if it is not **see**n

The masterworks of science revolve 'bout me

> The building block of life is Carbon, commonly known by the scientific symbol of **C**

You'll all be blind if it ain't me

> We are blind if we can't **see**

The rock has me, the sun hasn't

> Rock has letter **C** , not sun

But still

I fear only one

The one that doesn't let me go.

> Even travelling at velocity of c (light speed) does not escape a black hole.
>  OR
>  Gravity is the only thing that limits the **sea** to earth

You won't be here if you haven't me

> We can't be on Puzzling SE if we can't **see**

I am the Poseidon, the Apollo and have half your food

> Poseidon is the god of the **Sea**.
>  Apollo >> Honestly not sure about this, but I am reckoning that it is related to Apollo 11 landing on the **Sea** of Tranquility
>  Most food are chemically carbon-based, hence made mostly out of **C** atoms

I am in the black not in the white
I am in a chopper not in a plane

> Former contains letter **C**, not the latter

The literature worships me, for it be horrible if it ain't me.

> The **Sea** has many stories written about it, be it mythical, nautical fiction etc ....

Comment: If anyone else agrees with this answer and have suggestions for the missing lines, you could edit it in too .

Comment: You got the correct answer!! For the one explanation you haven't got yet, think what if c says "I'm very fast". Also take a look at the comments on other answers for it

Comment: Please update your answer with the remaining explanation so that I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Natasha edited!

Answer (score 1):

Could it be

> light?

The cave has me, the wind hasn't

> The wind cannot really get light, light goes through it for the most part, while caves at least have an entrance that gets light

The stories, the pirates, the demons, the lands...all nothing if it isn't me

> light is present in all of them

The masterworks of science revolve 'bout me

> speed of light, like Einstein's $E = mc^2$

You'll all be blind if it ain't me

> sight relies on light

The rock has me, the sun hasn't

> rocks do get light, but the sun loses light constantly

But still
I fear only one
The one that doesn't let me go.

> that would be the shadow I believe. Where there is light, there is darkness. **EDIT:** Or a black hole (credits to Arnaud Mortier in the comments)

Comment: The one that doesn't let me go would rather be a rot13(oynpx ubyr), right?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier That's actually very possible!

Comment: Your answer is very close as two of your explanations are also valid for the answer I've thought.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, here's my guess:

It might be

> dark

*The cave has me, the wind hasn't*

> I'm pretty sure that I'll find darkness inside a cave, and wind doesn't carry "dark". 
>  (What? Black smoke? No, that's the color from the matter within it!)

*The stories, the pirates, the demons, the lands...all nothing if it isn't me*

> Some stories could be dark, pirates are mostly dark(mentally, I mean), and lands... how could we found it easily without some "dark" while in the ocean?

*The masterworks of science revolve 'bout me*

> I guess it is talking about the research for the universe, including the [Dark matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter).

*You'll all be blind if it ain't me*

> A kind of protein named [visual purple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhodopsin) do exist in our eyes, so we could "see" in the dark. 
>  Completely darkness? Yeah, we might can't see, yet the visual acuity didn't get killed, meaning that we wouldn't be actually "blind". 
>  However, if there were no dark for our eyes... we could be completely blind.

*The rock has me, the sun hasn't*

> It looks like the same logic in first part, a rock could have some darkness, not only shadow, but hole/cave made by erosion. 
>  But sun... I know about sunspot, but usually we would see it without dark. 
>  If that's the case, there might need a [science](/questions/tagged/science) tag on the question.

*But still* 
*I fear only one* 
*The one that doesn't let me go.*

> *Light* would be the only one thing that limit dark.

Well... this looks a lot like the Bewilder's answer, yet OP has some clue below, which make this one more reasonable, so I would give it a shot.

Comment: This answer is good, but I was thinking of something else. I'd most probably have the science tag if your explanations for "you'll all be blind if it ain't me" was the one I thought.

Answer (score 0):

Is this

> The earth?

This fits all lines of the poem - wind and sun don't have this, rock and cave do. None of the stuff mentioned in lines 2-5 could exist without it.

As for the last part,

> Gravity hold the earth together and doesn't let go.

Comment: It's a good answer, but I was thinking of something else - something which is not a thing

Comment: How does "You'll all be blind if it ain't me" fit here?

Comment: Well, if you don't exist you can't see. Still a bit of a stretch, I suppose @Natasha

Comment: Okayy. But I'll still wait and see if the answer I'm thinking comes from anyone. Otherwise I'll most probably accept your answer.

Comment: Oh, for sure wait until you have the correct answer - if mine is incorrect, I would advise against accepting it, at least not so soon. No need to rush! You can signify that you like an answer without accepting it by upvoting it. (Not asking for an upvote; just an FYI for the future). @Natasha

Comment: By the way, I can't even upvote at the moment as I've reached the daily voting limit.

Comment: @Natasha no problem! Like I said, that was just an FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> A shadow

The cave has me, the wind hasn't

> A cave is naturally dark, and wind is too thin to project a visible shadow

The stories, the pirates, the demons, the lands...all nothing if it isn't me

> I believe this is referencing shadow theater, or the "actors" in Plato's Cave

The masterworks of science revolve 'bout me

> Science has spent a lot of time studying light, and therefore shadows by association

You'll all be blind if it ain't me

> The eyeballs project light onto a darkened surface to process images. Without shadows, this process could not work

The rock has me, the sun hasn't

> Because the sun is emitting light in all directions, it doesn't have a shadow by normal standards

But still / I fear only one / The one that doesn't let me go.

> A shadow can never be separated from the object that made it, because its existence depends on the object blocking light

Comment: Your answer is close, and in fact one of your explanations are also valid for the answer I've thought. Try thinking and a more basic level.